# JQuery-ui-autocomplete shows value in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jquery-ui-1.11.4 and autocomplete.  My source is obtained by ajax which is properly returning this type of JSON

```
[
  {"label":"foo", "value":"01-1013"},
  {"label":"bar", "value":"01-1003"}
]
```

When I scroll down to select my choice everything works correctly.  The value is added to printTag and the label is added to the text box (inputTag).  The problem is that as I use the down arrow to select my choice, the value is displayed in the text box, not the label.  The label is ONLY displayed in after I select my choice.

I read a couple of reviews and have tried to modify my code but I can't figure it out.  Here is my autocomplete.

```
$(inputTag).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: myAjaxFile,
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: getData+'='+ request.term,
            success: function(data){
                response(data)
            }
        });
    },
    focus: function(event, ui){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(inputTag).val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $(printTag).val(ui.item.value);
        // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
        event.preventDefault();
        $(inputTag).val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
    minLength: 2
});
```

How do I display the label in the text box rather than the value?

Comment: you are using selection by enter button ?

Comment: @Ansar - Yes, but the the problem occurs when I am hitting the up and down arrow.